Playwright with browserstack sdk integration throws - TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'wsEndpoint')
This is my browserstack.yml file
userName: ******
accessKey: *****
framework: playwright
platforms:
  - os: OS X
    osVersion: Ventura
    browserName: Chrome
    browserVersion: latest
browserstackLocal: false
buildName: playwright-js
buildIdentifier: ${BUILD_NUMBER}
projectName: playwright-js
debug: true
consoleLogs: verbose

This is the playwright.config.ts
import { defineConfig, devices } from '@playwright/test';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
  testDir: path.join(__dirname, "specs/smoke/plawright/tests"),
  fullyParallel: true,
  forbidOnly: !!process.env.CI,
  retries: process.env.CI ? 2 : 0,
  workers: process.env.CI ? 1 : undefined,
  use: {
    trace: 'on-first-retry',
  },

npx browserstack-node-sdk playwright test is the command that i am using and i get the 
Running 1 test using 1 worker
  1) [chrome@latest:OSX Ventura@browserstack] › example.spec.ts:18:7 › search from ** › ** ** 

    TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'wsEndpoint')

I was able to figure out that with the legacy integration
const cdpUrl = `wss://cdp.browserstack.com/playwright?caps=${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(capabilities))} i

s required. The problem with using legacy was, it was not allowing multiple configurations and neither was the configuration stable enough to run the test.
I tried both legacy and sdk.`

Please try adding logLeve: debug in browserstack.yml configuration file of your project and then please check the generated SDK log files in "log" folder for any error/exception.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
